# In Jquery Datatable i have a select filter , but for one filter i want datepicker to filter the dates,how it possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datatables

I have code that are giving three fields for the select filter, but i want on onr filed datepicker insted of all dates.

```
<script>
                        // to show the pages till 50
                        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        lengthMenu : [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]

    } );
} );

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var indexOfMyCol = 1 ;
    var indexOfMyCol1 = 2 ;

    $("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
        if(i === indexOfMyCol || i === indexOfMyCol1 ){ 
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                table.column( i )
                    .search( $(this).val() )
                    .draw();
            } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    }
    } );
} );

</script>
```

How i can put datepicker insted of all selected dates.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: i want in search option filter by datepicker,

Comment: use this `$('.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').datepicker();`

Comment: here are different examples for it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/wg3b6y7m/4/) & [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/y7quthe5/7/) & [this](https://coderexample.com/datatable-search-by-datepicker/) & [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1723/editable-with-datepicker-inside-datatables) -- can be helpful for you..